# Is it necessary to hide the system folder from search robots?

Tags: security, seo

Does this make any sense in a robots.txt?

User-Agent: *
Disallow: /your_system_folder

I'm guessing since the robots.txt file can be read it makes it even more dangerous to expose the system folder's name... but, is that folder hidden from bot's eyes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not put it in your robots.txt file. As you noted, it exposes the path to your system folder. Malicious bots or users will certainly look at that file and poke around the paths you have in there. So long as you don't have a hyperlink to your system folder in your site, an SEO bot won't stumble upon or find it anyways

Comment: I'd like to add that, if possible, put your system folder above the website's root so that it is impossible to navigate to it from the web. If you can't then I'd completely agree with this and never put a reference to your system folder in robots.txt or any other publicly accessible file.